# R: Lagging xts objects with dplyr loaded

Tags: r, dplyr, xts, lag

I am currently working on some codes that require both
transpose function from dplyr and lag function for xts.

lagging xts works fine on its own, but with dplyr loaded, it gives me the 
subscript out of bounds error.
How can I fix this??

```
require(xts)
xtx <- xts(cbind(a=1:4, b=11:14, c=21:24), order=Sys.Date() + 1:4)
```

lagging xtx works fine until dplyr is loaded.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Explicitly mention the package name, `packageName::functionName` ? For example, `dplyr::lag`

Comment: sorry. dplyr::lag masks stats::lag()

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of loading the packages. Load `dplyr` first, then `xts`. This will mask `lag` from dplyr by default

```
library(dplyr)
library(xts)
```

if you still are getting the wrong function call look up, as mentioned you can use `xts::lag`, where you want to apply the `xts` operator.